# Loading a css file to Magento

Tags: html, css, xml, magento

So I basically got my own whole css layout and I want to change the layout of my magento frontend. I've looked into this post: [How to apply CSS to Magento CMS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050668/how-to-apply-css-to-magento-cms-page) but it's not loading my css in. I did this:

I added to Custom Layout Update XML:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>csstest/style.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

and in my html editor I got this:

```
<div class="header">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="header_2">&nbsp;</div>
```

Css just in case:

```
.header{
width:80%;
margin-left:10%;
height:15%;

/*border-radius:12px; */
background-color:white;
}

.header_2{
width:80%;
margin-left:10%;
height:5%;
background-color:grey;
font-size:200%;
}
```

My style.css is in this directory:`/skin/frontend/default/csstest/` I also tried to put it in: `skin/frontend/default/default/css/`

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Do you get any console warning about whether the script was found or not?

Comment: @user3154108 when I went CTRL + U in firefox it didn't show the link rel="stylesheet" style.css. So he didn't went into the right directory or something? Or the config is bad?

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+k, it opens the console where warnings and errors are logged. If the file could not be found, the console will give you a warning and tell you where the file was sought. Such an error message would be helpful to figure out the problem.

Comment: try `/skin/frontend/default/default/csstest/`

Comment: @user3154108 I only get errors from a different css file:

05:20:49.306 Unknown property '-moz-opacity'.  Declaration dropped. styles.css:1006
05:20:49.309 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. styles.css:1525
05:20:49.309 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. styles.css:1692
05:20:49.309 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. styles.css:1696
05:20:49.309 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. styles.css:1696
05:20:50.529 Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss">
<stylesheet>../csstest/css/style.css</stylesheet>
<params>media="screen"</params></action>
</reference>
```

In Custom Layout Update XML

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple way to add your CSS styles?

Add it to `head.phtml`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('csstest/style.css') ?>">
```

Or add it to your `local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>csstest/style.css</file></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Don't forget to check your styles in right folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

put your csstest/style.css   in css folder

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>css/csstest/style.css/file></action>
```